# Import data from Excel to DataGridView - error System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'

Tags: c#, .net, excel, dataset, adapter

In excel file case i have the sheets: Sheet1

[image]

And Sheet2

[image]

When i'd like to import data from excel to datagridview i use that part of code:

```
  OleDbDataAdapter dta3 = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [Sheet2$].ID_MODULE, [Sheet1$].ID_PROJECT, [Sheet2$].NAME, [Sheet1$].PROJECT_NAME FROM [Sheet2$] INNER JOIN [Sheet1$] ON [Sheet1$].ID_PROJECT = [Sheet2$].ID_PROJECT;", oledbconn);
                    oledbconn.Open();

                    DataSet dsole3 = new DataSet();
                    dta3.Fill(dsole3, "Sheet2$");
                    datagrdvModules.DataSource = dsole3.Tables["Sheet2$"];
```

But then i have an error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more
>   required parameters.

And it shows at the line:

```
dta3.Fill(dsole3, "Sheet2$");
```

But maybe can be something different. I have question: Is it possible to fix that error? Thank you very much for any help or advice.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ControlDataBase
{
    public partial class New_Tables : Form
    {
        public New_Tables()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void ImportData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Files|*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xlsb;*.xltx;*.xltm;*.xls;*.xlt;*.xls;*.xml;*.xml;*.xlam;*.xla;*.xlw;*.xlr;", ValidateNames = true })
            {
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(ofd.FileName);
                    string FileName1 = ofd.FileName;

                    string excel = fi.FullName;

                    if (ofd.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                    {
                        StrConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;\"";
                    }

                    if (ofd.FileName.EndsWith(".xls"))
                    {
                        StrConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 1.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";
                    }
                    OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(StrConn);

                    OleDbDataAdapter dta3 = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [Sheet2$].ID_MODULE, [Sheet1$].ID_PROJECT, [Sheet2$].NAME, [Sheet1$].PROJECT_NAME FROM [Sheet2$] INNER JOIN [Sheet1$] ON [Sheet1$].ID_PROJECT = [Sheet2$].ID_PROJECT;", oledbconn);
                    oledbconn.Open();

                    DataSet dsole3 = new DataSet();
                    dta3.Fill(dsole3, "Sheet2$");
                    datagrdvModules.DataSource = dsole3.Tables["Sheet2$"];

                    oledbconn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see `Nazwa_Project_Name` in sheet1, wouldn't that just be `Project_Name`?

Comment: @CharlesMay edited and corrected.

Comment: You're joining on ID_Project but you have no values to match to in Sheet2. You should be getting a different error though. Are you sure this is a complete example of what your spreadsheets hold? Or did my original comment fix your problem?

Comment: I've edited that question but after testing that i have the same error which i described.

Comment: Try creating that exact workbook because I just did and threw your code into a new project and selected the workbook and received the expected data without issue. Be sure that your columns names match exactly what you have in the header row. Anything different will be considered a parameter and will throw that error.

Comment: OK @CharlesMay i've had mistaken by writing wrong column names and it works thx for any help this time :)

Comment: @CharlesMay i have a question: Now i've just erased values in ID_project column in Sheet2. Then i have got an error: `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: „Type mismatch in expression.” ` In ID_project have i to get values in this column in that Sheet?

Comment: The problem with blanking all the columns is that the type is no longer seen as numeric and your join can't compare the two. You could create a row at the top with -1 for all 3 values. This will git rid of that error and won't pull any matching results. I'm more curious though as to why you would have a row that is apparently related with a blank foreign key.